# How do I make recursive scraping work?

Tags: python, scrapy

My goal is to scrape a list of URLs and headlines from a site, as part of a larger project-which is what drove me to learn scrapy. Now, as it stands, using basespider to scrape the first page of a given date (format is /archive/date/) works fine. However, trying to use crawlspider (working off some tutorials) to scrape each sequential page of a given date isn't working, and I'm not sure why. I've tried a number of solution.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from physurlfetch.items import PhysurlfetchItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class PhysURLSpider(CrawlSpider):
    date = raw_input("Please iput a date in the format M-DD-YYYY: ")
    name = "PhysURLCrawlSpider"
    allowed_domains = "phys.org"
    start_url_str = ("http://phys.org/archive/%s/") % (date)
    start_urls = [start_url_str]

    rules = (
        Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("\d\.html",)), 
        callback="parse_items", follow = True),
    )

    #def parse_start_url(self, response):
        #request = Request(start_urls, callback = self.parse_items)


    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//article[@class='news-box news-detail-box     clearfix']/h4")
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = PhysurlfetchItem()
            item ["title"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
            item ["link"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Currently I have parse_start_url commented out because that was failing with the method I was trying to snag start_urls (with the varying string). Running this currently jumps straight to page 2 of a given day without grabbing any data from page 1, and then stops (no page 2 data, no page 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran your spider locally (using `scrapy runspider yourspider.py`) I got this console output:

```
2014-01-10 13:30:19+0100 [PhysURLCrawlSpider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/> (referer: None)
2014-01-10 13:30:19+0100 [PhysURLCrawlSpider] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'phys.org': <GET http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/page2.html>
2014-01-10 13:30:19+0100 [PhysURLCrawlSpider] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

You can see Scrapy is filetring an offsite query. In fact `allowed_domains` should be a list of domains, so if you change to `allowed_domains = ["phys.org"]` you get further:

```
2014-01-10 13:32:00+0100 [PhysURLCrawlSpider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/> (referer: None)
2014-01-10 13:32:00+0100 [PhysURLCrawlSpider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/page2.html> (referer: http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/)
2014-01-10 13:32:00+0100 [PhysURLCrawlSpider] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/page3.html> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_CLASS)
2014-01-10 13:32:01+0100 [PhysURLCrawlSpider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/page8.html> (referer: http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/)
2014-01-10 13:32:01+0100 [PhysURLCrawlSpider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/page6.html> (referer: http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/)
2014-01-10 13:32:01+0100 [PhysURLCrawlSpider] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/> from <GET http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/page1.html>
2014-01-10 13:32:01+0100 [PhysURLCrawlSpider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/page4.html> (referer: http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/)
2014-01-10 13:32:01+0100 [PhysURLCrawlSpider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/page7.html> (referer: http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/)
2014-01-10 13:32:01+0100 [PhysURLCrawlSpider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/page5.html> (referer: http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/)
2014-01-10 13:32:01+0100 [PhysURLCrawlSpider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/page3.html> (referer: http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/)
2014-01-10 13:32:01+0100 [PhysURLCrawlSpider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/> (referer: http://phys.org/archive/5-12-2013/page2.html)
2014-01-10 13:32:01+0100 [PhysURLCrawlSpider] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

But the spider is not picking up any item. It may or may not be a typo but your XPath expression for `titles` should probably be `//article[@class='news-box news-detail-box clearfix']/h4`, i.e. without the extra whitespace before `clearfix`.

As a final note, if you use the latest Scrapy version (from version [0.20.0](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#released-2013-11-08) onwards), you'll be able to use [CSS selectors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html), which can be more readable than XPath when selecting elements with multiple classes:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from physurlfetch.items import PhysurlfetchItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class PhysURLSpider(CrawlSpider):
    date = raw_input("Please iput a date in the format M-DD-YYYY: ")
    name = "PhysURLCrawlSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["phys.org"]
    start_url_str = ("http://phys.org/archive/%s/") % (date)
    start_urls = [start_url_str]

    rules = (
        Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("\d\.html",)),
        callback="parse_items", follow = True),
    )

    #def parse_start_url(self, response):
        #request = Request(start_urls, callback = self.parse_items)


    def parse_items(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)

        # selecting only using "news-detail-box" class
        # you could use "article.news-box.news-detail-box.clearfix > h4"
        titles = selector.css("article.news-detail-box > h4")

        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = PhysurlfetchItem()
            item ["title"] = titles.xpath("a/text()").extract()
            item ["link"] = titles.xpath("a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
        self.log("%d items in %s" % (len(items), response.url))
        return items
```